# I want to take the color in imageView and save it in Firebase

Tags: java, android

[image]

I want to save the color I selected it before to the Firebase. I tried

```
favoritColor.getDrawableState();
```

and

```
favoritColor.getDrawable();
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: When you're using some sort of color picker for selecting the color, then why aren't you directly using the selected color??

Comment: it doesnt work 
i want to save the color code in firebase but the value of selected color strang value